# Spring boot cache not working with @PostConstruct or @AfterPropertiesSet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I try to initialize my cache with data, when my application start, and that's not working.
My code:

springBootApplication

```
package com.r2b.springcache;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan("com.r2b")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class SpringCacheApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCacheApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("student");
    }
}
```

student

```
package com.r2b.model;

public class Student {

    String id;
    String name;
    String clz;

    public Student(String id, String name, String clz) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.clz = clz;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClz() {
        return clz;
    }

    public void setClz(String clz) {
        this.clz = clz;
    }

    //Setters and getters

}
```

studentService

```
package com.r2b.service;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.r2b.model.Student;

@Service
public class StudentService  
{

    @Cacheable("student")
    public Student getStudentByID(String id)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Going to sleep for 5 Secs.. to simulate backend call.");
            Thread.sleep(1000*5);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Student(id,"Sajal" ,"V");
    }

}
```

StudentController

```
package com.r2b.controller;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.r2b.model.Student;
import com.r2b.service.StudentService;

@RestController
public class StudentController
{

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        studentService.getStudentByID("1");
    }

    @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public Student findStudentById(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        System.out.println("Searching by ID  : " + id);

        return studentService.getStudentByID(id);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.r2b</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-cache</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

when I go to http://localhost:8080/student/1 the first time, the cache is not active, and the response takes more than 5 seconds, but when I refresh, the cache responds, and the request takes a few milliseconds ! despite that I called the cache method in postConstruct, i have try with @AfterPropertiesSet and it not working too !

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Title should be in English please.

Comment: Is your `init()` method actually being executed?

Comment: Yes, it being executed when spring starting

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is simple, but it took me ***almost a day*** to figure out methods decorated with [@Cacheable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) have no effect in a [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

**Simply** replace your [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) with a [@EventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html)(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void init() {
    studentService.getStudentByID("1");
}
```

***NB If an exception gets thrown from a method decorated with [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) or [EventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html)(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) event your application will exit...***

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because the proxy has not been initialized yet. This is actually [documented in the user guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable)

> In proxy mode (the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object that calls another method of the target object) does not lead to actual caching at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Cacheable. Consider using the aspectj mode in this case. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behavior, so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code (that is, @PostConstruct).

This is exactly what you're doing here. Caching should be as transparent as possible so pre-loading the cache on startup looks a bit odd to me (and increase the startup time).

Comment: can you post an example of aspectj configuration if possible ?

Comment: if i set a method that i run in asynchronous 1 minutes after loading the context spring, is not it cleaner than using aspectj?